# how to sent project id to the database in Laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I need insert some project id which display in My web browser address bar. I am using Laravel  5.2

```
lacalhost:8000/project/06
```

I need to insert this number 06 to project_id column of gantt_task table.

this is My GanttController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\GanttTask;
use App\GanttLink;
use Dhtmlx\Connector\GanttConnector;

class GanttController extends Controller
{
    public function data() {
        $connector = new GanttConnector(null, "PHPLaravel");
        $connector->render_links(new GanttLink(), "id", "source,target,type");
        $connector->render_table(new GanttTask(),"id","start_date,duration,text,progress,parent,project_id");
    }

}
```

this is My Gantttask Model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GanttTask extends Model
{
    protected $table = "gantt_tasks";
    public $primaryKey = "id";
    public $timestamps = false;
}


 can you give me some solutions?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\GanttTask;
use App\GanttLink;
use Dhtmlx\Connector\GanttConnector;

class GanttController extends Controller
{
    public function data(Request $request, $project_id) {
        $connector = new GanttConnector(null, "PHPLaravel");
        $connector->render_links(new GanttLink(), "id", "source,target,type");

        // Passing as argument project_id variable to model constructor
        // new GanttTask(compact('project_id'))  will create object
        // but will not save to database, 
        // so You can use: 
        // GanttTask::create(compact('project_id'))  to push to db
        $connector->render_table(new GanttTask(compact('project_id')),"id","start_date,duration,text,progress,parent,project_id");
    }

}
```

Model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GanttTask extends Model
{
    protected $table = "gantt_tasks";
    public $timestamps = false;

    // add fillable to be able to set arguments in model constructor
    protected $fillable = [
      'start_date', 
      'duration',
      'text', 
      'progress',
      'parent',
      'project_id'
   ];
}
```

Comment: I tryied your solutoion. little bit different understand comments in your controller. can you explain it simply?

Comment: new GanttTask(compact('project_id'))  is like new GanttTask(['project_id'=>$project_id])  but it does not save it to database, it just creates object in memory. But if You want also to save it to db, so better do: GanttTask::create(compact('project_id'))   it will create record in db and return object.

Comment: about $fillable, it's convenience for eloquent to use ::create method on object.

Comment: @Fernando feel free to use any code You want that's shared by anyone in Stackoverflow (: